# Passing variables to elasticsearch query node js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Does anyone know the proper syntax of passing variables to elasticsearch query in node js? Here is my code:

```js
client.search({
    index: 'esri-pc6-2017r1',
    body: {
      "query": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "geometry": {
            "relation": "within",
            "shape": {
              "type": "polygon",
               coordinates: [["$polygon"]]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
})
```

`polygon` is an array that needs to be passed to coordinates field in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this type `polygon` needs a list of a list of points, so, it is an array within an array.

We can do this :

```
const index = 'esri-pc6-2017r1'
const $polygon = [
    [1000.0, -1001.0],
    [1001.0, -1001.0],
    [1001.0, -1000.0],
    [1000.0, -1000.0],
    [1000.0, -1001.0],
];
const body = {
    query: {
        geo_shape: {
            geometry: {
                relation: 'within',
                shape: {
                    type: 'polygon',
                    coordinates: $polygon,
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

return client.search({
    index: index,
    body: body,
});
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If this has solved the problem, you can help other by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/919289) the answer